# change decimal place in textbox using numericUpDown

Tags: c#, winforms, decimal, numericupdown

Im using Visual Studio 2010, windows form (c#).

I need change decimals place of value in textbox using numericUpDown1.

example:

[image]   [image]

[image] [image]

[image] [image]

[image] [image]

[image] [image]

I tryed this code:

```
private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

      //  tbxConvertito.Text = (decimal.Parse(tbxConvertito.Text) * 10m).ToString();

        if (numericUpDown1.Value == 0)
        {
            int decimalPlace = 0;
           // Decimal xDecimal = decimal.Parse(tbxConvertito.text);

            decimal xDecimal = decimal.Parse(tbxConvertito.Text);
            tbxConvertito.Text = (Math.Round(xDecimal, decimalPlace)).ToString();
        }

        if (numericUpDown1.Value == 1)
        {
            int decimalPlace = 1;
            // Decimal xDecimal = decimal.Parse(tbxConvertito.text);

            decimal xDecimal = decimal.Parse(tbxConvertito.Text);
            tbxConvertito.Text = (Math.Round(xDecimal, decimalPlace)).ToString();
        }

    }
```

but not work. How can I solve this, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create field with decimal value, to keep original value.

If you do that:

```
int decimalPlace = 1;
decimal xDecimal = decimal.Parse(tbxConvertito.Text);
tbxConvertito.Text = (Math.Round(xDecimal, decimalPlace)).ToString();
```

You lose original value of your decimal variable.

Try this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
        public decimal myDecimal = 3755.25012345M;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            tbxConvertito.Text = myDecimal.ToString();

            numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }

        private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {          
            int decimalPlace = (int)numericUpDown1.Value;
            tbxConvertito.Text = Decimal.Round(myDecimal, decimalPlace).ToString();
        }
}
```

Solution without use `Round` method:

```
  public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public decimal myDecimal = 3755.25012345M;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            tbxConvertito.Text = myDecimal.ToString();

            numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }

        private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {          
            int decimalPlace = (int)numericUpDown1.Value;

            string[] numbers = myDecimal.ToString().Split(new char[] { '.', ',' });

            string tmp = string.Empty;

            if (decimalPlace <= numbers[1].Length)
            {
                tmp = "," + numbers[1].Substring(0, decimalPlace);

                if (tmp.EndsWith(","))
                    tmp = string.Empty;
            }
            else
                tmp = "," + numbers[1];

            tbxConvertito.Text = numbers[0] + tmp;
        }
    }
```

Comment: this is correct and i guess the OP want to replace the `.` to `,` so you can add `.Replace(".", ",");` +1 :)

Comment: @vincenzolopalo what is value of myDecimal ?

Comment: @vincenzolopalo try change this line: `string[] numbers = myDecimal.ToString().Split(new char[] { '.' });` to this one: `string[] numbers = myDecimal.ToString().Split(new char[] { '.', ',' });`

Comment: @kmatyaszek this code work very good if mydecimal is iniziatiled, but if mydecimal is a value typed in textbox?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using `String` operations. Try this one

```
decimal xDecimal = decimal.Parse(tbxConvertito.Text);
string str = xDecimal.ToString();
if (!str.Contains(","))
            decimalPlace--;
tbxConvertito.Text = str.Replace(",", "").Insert((str.Length-1) - decimalPlace,",");
```

And use it like this in your code

```
private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

  //  tbxConvertito.Text = (decimal.Parse(tbxConvertito.Text) * 10m).ToString();

    if (numericUpDown1.Value == 0)
    {
        int decimalPlace = 0;
       // Decimal xDecimal = decimal.Parse(tbxConvertito.text);

        decimal xDecimal = decimal.Parse(tbxConvertito.Text);
        string str = xDecimal.ToString();
        if (!str.Contains(","))
            decimalPlace--;
        tbxConvertito.Text = str.Replace(",", "").Insert((str.Length-1) - decimalPlace,",");
    }

    if (numericUpDown1.Value == 1)
    {
        int decimalPlace = 1;
        // Decimal xDecimal = decimal.Parse(tbxConvertito.text);

        decimal xDecimal = decimal.Parse(tbxConvertito.Text);
        string str = xDecimal.ToString();
        if (!str.Contains(","))
            decimalPlace--;
        tbxConvertito.Text = str.Replace(",", "").Insert((str.Length-1) - decimalPlace,",");
    }

}
```

Comment: sir, did you test your answer? :)

Comment: @vincenzolopalo I prepared you solution without use Round method. Check my answer again.