# Change decimal place in textbox value with numericUpDown

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, numericupdown

With this code I can modify decimal place, using `numericUpDown`. This code works if I `initialize` *`myDecimal`* variable. But I need modify `decimal` place to a value typed in `textbox`.

In other word `myDecimal = tbxConvertito.Text`. But in this case, code not work.

Check screenshot in this page please: [change decimal place in textbox using numericUpDown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14414138/change-decimal-place-in-textbox-using-numericupdown/14414478#comment20061224_14414478)

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public decimal myDecimal = 3755.25012345M;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        tbxConvertito.Text = myDecimal.ToString();
        numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {          
        int decimalPlace = (int)numericUpDown1.Value;
        string[] numbers = myDecimal.ToString().Split(new char[] { '.', ',' });
        string tmp = string.Empty;
        if (decimalPlace <= numbers[1].Length)
        {
            tmp = "," + numbers[1].Substring(0, decimalPlace);

            if (tmp.EndsWith(","))
                tmp = string.Empty;
        }
        else
            tmp = "," + numbers[1];

        tbxConvertito.Text = numbers[0] + tmp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split property `Text` from `tbxConvertito`.

Also when text will be changed in TextBox you must invoke `numericUpDown1_ValueChanged` to restrict settings in NumericUpDown.

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public decimal myDecimal = 3755.25012345M;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            tbxConvertito.Text = myDecimal.ToString();                        
            numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }

        private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {          
            int decimalPlace = (int)numericUpDown1.Value;                        

            string[] numbers = tbxConvertito.Text.Split(new char[] { '.', ',' });

            string tmp = string.Empty;
            if (numbers.Length != 1)
            {
                if (decimalPlace <= numbers[1].Length)
                {
                    tmp = "," + numbers[1].Substring(0, decimalPlace);

                    if (tmp.EndsWith(","))
                        tmp = string.Empty;
                }
                else
                    tmp = "," + numbers[1];                
            }
            tbxConvertito.Text = numbers[0] + tmp; 
            tbxConvertito.Select(tbxConvertito.Text.Length, 0);
        }

        private void tbxConvertito_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            decimal.TryParse(tbxConvertito.Text.Replace(',', '.'), out myDecimal);
        }
    }
```

Without lose data:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public decimal myDecimal = 0;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            // init value
            tbxConvertito.Text = myDecimal.ToString();
            numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }

        private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int decimalPlace = (int)numericUpDown1.Value;

            string[] numbers = myDecimal.ToString().Split(new char[] { '.', ',' });

            string tmp = string.Empty;
            if (numbers.Length != 1)
            {
                if (decimalPlace <= numbers[1].Length)
                {
                    tmp = "," + numbers[1].Substring(0, decimalPlace);

                    if (tmp.EndsWith(","))
                        tmp = string.Empty;
                }
                else
                    tmp = "," + numbers[1];
            }
            tbxConvertito.Text = numbers[0] + tmp;

            tbxConvertito.Select(tbxConvertito.Text.Length, 0);
        }

        private void tbxConvertito_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (keyValue == 188) return;
            if (keyPressed)
            {
                string stringValue = tbxConvertito.Text;
                if ((stringValue.Contains(',') && stringValue.Split(new char[] { ',' })[1].Length <= (int)numericUpDown1.Value) || !stringValue.Contains(','))
                    decimal.TryParse(tbxConvertito.Text.Replace(',', '.'), out myDecimal);
                keyPressed = false;
            }
            numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            Console.WriteLine("Displayed value: {0}", tbxConvertito.Text);
            Console.WriteLine("Actual value: {0}", myDecimal);
        }

        bool keyPressed = false;
        int keyValue;

        private void tbxConvertito_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            keyValue = e.KeyValue;
            keyPressed = true;
        }
    }
```

Scenarios:

1. [Decimal Places = 0] you can type e.g. [1], [1234], [12345]
2. [Decimal Places = 1] you can type e.g. [1,1], [1234], [12345,3]
   if
   you change value in NumericUpDown to 0 displayed value will be [1],
   [1234], [12345]
   if you change value in NumericUpDown to 1 again
   displayed value will be [1,1], [1234], [12345,3]
3. [Decimal Places = 1] the same situation as for step 2

Now we don't lose any data. We update our original data only if user will type something in our textbox.

Comment: done, but not work, because I lose original value of my decimal variable.

Comment: @vincenzolopalo you can parse value from textbox to decimal variable. Check tbxConvertito_TextChanged again.

Comment: I dont need this row:
public decimal myDecimal = 3755.25012345M;

I have not initialize value, because value is placed in textbox.

Comment: @vincenzolopalo Yes, you don't need this but you can have this to store actual decimal value.

Comment: actual value is not constant, its variable and depend from value that I type in textbox. anyhow, not work code, because I lose original value :(

Comment: @vincenzolopalo so you can set zero to myDecimal (`public decimal myDecimal = 0;`) and everything will be ok.

Comment: its incredible, but not work, because I lose value, I mean: if I move from 4 to 3 decimal (example: 2,745 to 2,74) I cant go back to 2,745

Comment: @vincenzolopalo I added you solution without lose data. Check my answer again.

Comment: hello @kmatyaszek, its really incredible, but also this solution not work. I have add your code in new project (visual studio 2010, windows form) to test without risk of incompatibility, without luck. Can you send me your solution, so Can I test it? Its really frustrating...

Comment: @vincenzolopalo Yes, of course. Here is solution: http://sdrv.ms/U9S5y6 (NumericUpDownDecimalPlace.zip)

Comment: check this link please [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6v8hg3qfs8yrmec/READ_ME.txt)

Comment: @vincenzolopalo I added scenarios to my answer. You can check value of variables in output window, I write there some information about actual value of variables. Check it again.

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try

```
    private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //var ix = tbxConvertito.Text.IndexOf(',');
        decimal myDecimal = 0;
        bool IsDecimal = decimal.TryParse(tbxConvertito.Text, out myDecimal);
        if (IsDecimal)
        {
            decimal letDivide = myDecimal / 100;
            int decimalPlace = (int)numericUpDown1.Value;
            tbxConvertito.Text = letDivide.ToString().Replace(".", "");

            var index = tbxConvertito.Text.Length - decimalPlace;
            if (index > -1)
                tbxConvertito.Text = tbxConvertito.Text.Insert(index, ",");
            else
                tbxConvertito.Text = tbxConvertito.Text.Insert(1, ",");
        }
        else
        {
            tbxConvertito.Text = tbxConvertito.Text.ToString().Replace(",", "");
        }

    }
```

Comment: not work @spajce , value is view with two comma and lose original value

Comment: two comma? I tested the code and I have one only comma showed.

Comment: Did your `tbxConvertito` has `DataBinding`?

Comment: tbxConvertito has not DataBinding

Comment: I don't know what the actually happen why two commas showed in my answer with your `16150515` value when you tested. because i tested the code with your value its only one comma